# Executing terminal command in objective C with Dynamic path

Tags: objective-c, xcode, terminal

May be my question is a repeated question but I searched a lot of it on the internet and can't find the appropriate and helpful solution.
I want to run the terminal command `'mv'` for moving a folder from the root '~/' to another folder but its not working command is running properly using the NSTask library but I think the path is not correct my xcode compiler doest find '~/Desktop',

Sample Code:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/mv"];
[task setArguments:@[ @"~/Desktop/Script",@"~/Desktop/Script2"]];
[task launch];
```

and it gives error:

```
mv: rename ~/Desktop/Script to ~/Desktop/Script2: No such file or directory
```

I think the '~/' is not working and xcode cant find the file,
please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~ directory is not expanded as you have suspected.

You should use [NSHomeDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory) and concatenate.

Comment: Thanks for the instant and quick help :)